# Can a tourist pre-book and travel with Indre Namdal Trafikk bus line 17-599 Namsskogan – Smalåsen?

Tags: buses, norway

According to various travel planners, including [Entur](https://en-tur.no/stop-place-detail?from[name]=Namsskogan%20stasjon&from[stop][gtfsId]=NSR%3AQuay%3A76384&from[stop][parentStation][gtfsId]=NSR%3AStopPlace%3A44429&to[name]=Smal%C3%A5sen&to[stop][gtfsId]=NSR%3AQuay%3A76479&to[stop][parentStation][gtfsId]=NSR%3AStopPlace%3A44479&startTime=1516099320000), [Opentripplanner](http://otpdebug.entur.org/?module=planner&fromPlace=64.92754295730302%2C13.160076141357422&toPlace=Smal%C3%A5sen%20%20%28RB%3ANSR%3AStopPlace%3A44479%29%3A%3A65.079769%2C13.316428&time=03%3A00am&date=01-15-2018&mode=TRANSIT%2CWALK&maxWalkDistance=2000&arriveBy=false&wheelchair=false&locale=en&startTransitStopId=RB_NSR%3AQuay%3A76437&originalQueryTime=1516035180000&itinIndex=0) and [Transitfeeds](https://transitfeeds.com/p/norsk-reiseinformasjon-as/791/latest/trip/000375-0191085-), there is a 03:28 bus from [Namsskogan stasjon](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namsskogan_stasjon) to [Smalåsen](http://norgeskart.no/#!?project=seeiendom&layers=1004,1015&zoom=11&lat=7218441.56&lon=421747.52), presumably timed to correspond with the arrival of the [train from Trondheim](https://www.nsb.no/rutetider/rutetabell/_attachment/14683?_ts=160db48ea11).  I can find very little other information on this bus, other than that it is a *bestillingsrute*, driving only on request.  It is apparently operated by *Indre Namdal Trafikk A/S* who appear to have no internet presence.  I found a [2012/2013 timetable](http://visitnamsskogan.no/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/rutehefte_vinter_2012_13_ver_05.pdf) (6 years old) that does not mention this bus line to Smalåsen, but it does explain that *Bestillingstransport består av tilbringertransport og servicetransport.* and *Tilbringertransport gjelder alle som bor eller
oppholder seg i nevnte kommuner og har lengre avstand til buss og togstopp enn 2 km.* and *Servicetransport er for deg som trenger transport til
butikk, bank, postkontor eller andre service kontorer.
Transporten kjøres på faste dager til faste tider.* which appears to mean it's a pre-order bus (no surprise there) and/or only for residents or for transport to shop, bank, post office, etc (and then only twice a week).  Neither of those apply to me and according to the aforementioned sources the 17-599 appears to run every weekday.  Can I, as a tourist, pre-order transport on this bus 17-599 to travel to Smalåsen (gateway to [Børgefjell National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B8rgefjell_National_Park), in case anyone wonders why) in connection with an arriving train?

Comment: Just as a comment, it is almost as close to the national park to just stay on the train until **Majavatn** and then walk directly from there into the park. There is a trail called "Jengelvegen" - which I never knew had a name, that proceeds directly into the national park. I haven't walked all the way from there myself, but it looks spectacular on the map. Just food for thought!

Comment: @StianYttervik The night train does not call at Majavatn (assuming | in timetable means no stop; see *train from Trondheim* link).  It calls at Trong, Namsskogan (request stop), then Trofors.  However, on my way back I am likely to board the train in Majavatn to catch my flight back from Værnes in the evening.  Thanks for the Jengelvegen pointer though, I should check that out!

Comment: Ah, then I understand. (I think it would be easier to go to Majavatn from Namsskogan though, that is directly on the E6, the main road going north/south - hitch-hiking or by bus). Of course, if you arrive at night you might very well be better off with your original suggestion. I won't try to compel you to change plan, sounds like you have been thorough. Have a good hike!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just asked the [customer service](https://www.atb.no/en/contact-us/) and there is a bus service operating on demand between Namsskogan station and Smalåsen for every train stopping in Namsskogan.

The service must be ordered in advance, either by contacting customer service by phone +4707417 or +4775771861 (the short service number is not necessarily reachable from outside Norway).

The price for an adult ticket is 60 NOK if paid cash, or 37 NOK if paid with T:kort (an electronic prepaid travel card) or with the Mobilett app.

Comment: Takk!  Being on-demand presumably implies it waits for a delayed train, too.

Comment: @gerrit I didn't ask, but I would very much expect the bus to wait if the train is delayed. Even with 'regular', scheduled transport in Norway, connecting services often wait for delayed incoming transport, at least if the departures are very infrequent.

Comment: About +47 07417: I don't think you can call Norwegian 5-digit phone numbers that easily from abroad. I have tried in the past, and it has not worked. Things may have changed, but I would go for the other phone number to be safe. Also, please use spaces in phone numbers to make them easier to read. The Norwegian standard for 8-digit phone numbers (excluding those beginning with 4 or 9) would make it +47 75 51 18 61.

Comment: @Arthur As I already wrote, it depends on where you are calling from. I am abroad and can call the number from my cell phone, but not from my fixed line. The problem is usually not the number length, but that the five digit numbers are charged at a higher rate, which a foreign phone operator may not be willing to cover.  For the same reason, you may also not be able to call 8-digit numbers starting with 810 or 815 from abroad, as these are also charged at a higher rate.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I would guess that that also goes for 829-numbers. But yes, I was a bit quick there. As we say here in Norway: sorry.

Comment: Looks like the linked website is down.

Comment: @gerrit The web site is moved to a new URL and there does not seem to be possible to contact customer service by chat anymore. I have updated the answer.